# Interact with webview from method outside OnCreate in android

Tags: android

I have a question thta keeps occuring and i was wondering how to fix it. I want to be able to interact with views, in this case specifically the webview from outside the oncreate so that my methods can interact with the webview defined in the oncreate.

Here is an example of what im trying to do. In the search voice array im checked to see if the user said "go" and if they did i want either the go button to be pressed or to simply execute the code that the go button would do. I hope i explained this well enough, if you need clarification please let me know, thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class web extends Activity {
    static final int check = 111;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web);
        final WebView webBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webBrowser.setWebViewClient(new cpViewClient());
        webBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webBrowser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webBrowser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webBrowser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        Button bGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);
        Button bBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        Button bForward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forward);
        Button bRefresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        Button bClearHistory = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearhistory);
        final EditText etUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);

        bGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String enteredUrl = etUrl.getText().toString();
                enteredUrl = enteredUrl.toLowerCase();
                int len = enteredUrl.length();
                /*
                 * if (enteredUrl.substring(0, 3).equals("www")) enteredUrl =
                 * "http://" + enteredUrl; else if (enteredUrl.substring(0,
                 * 11).equals("http://www.")) //Do nothing its perfect
                 * Log.d("URL", "The Url is fine"); else enteredUrl =
                 * "http://www." + enteredUrl;
                 * 
                 * String dot1 = enteredUrl.substring(len-5, len-4); String dot2
                 * = enteredUrl.substring(len-4, len-3); if (!dot1.equals(".")
                 * || !dot2.equals(".")) enteredUrl = enteredUrl + ".com";
                 */
                if (enteredUrl.indexOf("http://") == -1
                        & enteredUrl.indexOf("www.") == -1) {
                    enteredUrl = "http://www." + enteredUrl;
                } else if (enteredUrl.indexOf("http://") == -1) {
                    enteredUrl = "http://" + enteredUrl;
                }

                if (enteredUrl.indexOf(".com") == -1
                        & enteredUrl.indexOf(".org") == -1
                        & enteredUrl.indexOf(".net") == -1
                        & enteredUrl.indexOf(".mil") == -1
                        & enteredUrl.indexOf(".gov") == -1
                        & enteredUrl.indexOf(".edu") == -1
                        & enteredUrl.indexOf(".info") == -1) {
                    enteredUrl = enteredUrl + ".com";
                }

                webBrowser.loadUrl(enteredUrl);
                etUrl.setText(enteredUrl);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etUrl.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }

        });
        bBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (webBrowser.canGoBack())
                    webBrowser.goBack();
            }

        });
        bForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (webBrowser.canGoForward())
                    webBrowser.goForward();
            }

        });
        bRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                webBrowser.reload();
            }

        });
        bClearHistory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                webBrowser.clearHistory();
            }

        });
        Button VR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.webvoice);
        VR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getvoice();
            }

        });



    }
    public void getvoice() {
        Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        startActivityForResult(i, check);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            final TextView tvvoicearray = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvvoicearray);
            tvvoicearray.setText(result.get(0));
            searchvoicearray();
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void searchvoicearray() {
        // Log.d("DEBUGGINGG",result.get(0));
        // System.out.println(result);
        int size = result.size();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < size) {
            String s = result.get(i);
            // next line removes all spaces in the string
            // s= s.replaceAll(" ", "");
            if (s.indexOf("go") != -1 ) {
                i = size;
                //i want the button go to be pressed or its action to be completed.

                if (webBrowser.canGoBack())
                webBrowser.goBack();
            } 

            else if (s.indexOf("back") != -1) {
                i = size;
                if (webBrowser.canGoBack())
                    webBrowser.goBack();
            } 

            else {
                System.out.println(result.get(i) + " is not internet");
                Log.d("DEBUGGINGG", result.get(i) + " is not internet");
                // }
                i++;
            }
        }

    }

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, declare webview outside `onCreate`:

```
static final int check = 111;
private WebView webBrowser;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web);
    webBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the WebView a member of your **web** class and not variable that is local to the onCreate() method: To do this you simply move its declaration outside the method:

```
public class web extends Activity {

    //Declare your member objects/variables here
    static final int check = 111;
    WebView webBrowser;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web);
        webBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        ...
        }
...        
}
```